# Blueimp Jquery file upload thumbnail after upload not resizing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to the use the [Blueimp Jquery File upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) in my MVC4 Project. I have implemented everything and it is working. I used the [MVC Example by MaxPavlov](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3) .

The upload works 100%, the only problem I have is that the thumbnail that is shown after the upload is not resized properly. I might only miss a script that I need to include.

Here is the scripts in the order that I include them on my page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/load-image.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/canvas-to-blob.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-fp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/FileUpload/locale.js"></script>
```

The templates I also copied as they are in the MVC Example.

When I select the image from my computer when running the application, then the thumbnail is the correct size, then I click on "upload" the files are uploaded and when it is displayed afterwards, my image is the same size as the image on disk. I tried setting the `.preview` class in the css, this works in chrome/firefox but not in IE.

Comment: Did you ever solve the thumbnail issue?  My issue is that the preview of the image is not the correct one (it's the default one I believe)

Comment: Hi, I do not have the code with me now. I think I added the width and height i wanted it to be to the style for the image.